# In Python, stylistically better way to remove a potentially nonexistent key from a dictionary?

Tags: python

Say you have a dictionary `some_dict` and want to make sure there's no key `some_key` in it. What's the best way to do this stylistically speaking and why?

**Option 1**

```
some_dict.pop(some_key, None)
```

**Option 2**

```
try:
    del some_dict[some_key]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

**Option 3**

```
if some_key in some_dict:
    del some_dict[some_key]
```

Also feel free to suggest another option.

Comment: If you happen to need a separate copy there's always `copied_dict = { k : v for (k,v) in some_dict.iteritems() if k != some_key }`. (or `items()` instead of `iteritems()` in python 3)

Answer (score 4):

Option 1 looks perfect to me. It does the job in one line and is easy to read.

Comment: That's what my first instinct is too. But I have a niggle. It's seems implicit (and therefore less Pythonic) that I don't care about the value of `some_key`. In Option 3, my intention that I only care about deleting the key, not its value, is explicit. Of course Option 3 probably slower, but negligibly so in almost all cases. Thoughts?

Comment: @Ghopper21 To me it is perfectly clear that you don't care about the value. If you did you would assign it somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Option 2 vs Option 3 is the classic "EAFP vs LBYL" question (see [glossary](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)). Option 2 is the preferred style.

I don't like Option 1 since the intent isn't clear. You are specifying a *default* argument only for the side effect of it preventing `KeyError` from being raised, but the argument itself has nothing to do with your intent (`None` could be substituted with anything, in fact). However it is most likely the fastest option, since it's implemented in native code.

Comment: +1. Nice reminder re: EAFP v LBYL, which I certain agree with, but I wonder if that's taking the principle too far in such a localized case. Option 3 just seems slightly more... clear in terms of basic code reading and communication of intent.

Comment: @Ghopper21 I think they are both as clear, because seeing "KeyError" in the context of that statement communicates the same information as the `if`. It also communicates that you *assume* the key exists, while an `if` is neutral.

Comment: Good point about assumption. In the specific case which caused me to ask this quesiton, I'm generally assuming it's NOT there, which is why I may explain my (current) instinctive preference for Option 3.

Comment: Btw, yes, the fact that `None` could be anything in Option 1 is what gave me pause as I was writing that in my code.

Comment: If performance matters, I suspect that in Option 2, creating the exception to be caught would incur some overhead.

Comment: @200_success Yes, but of course that's only if there is one to be caught. So for performance you need to consider which case is more likely. If the exception will only be raised a few times per several iterations, allowing it to happen will save more time overall than checking on each iteration.